# Using mailutils-config to set askcc to False

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu, configuration, sendmail

When it comes to email configuration, I am not a smart man.  I know I need to use mailutils-config or mu-tools to change the default value of 'askcc' to False, likely in an /etc/mailutils.rc file ... However, this file doesn't exist.  Do I populate it myself and then alter the settings?  Is there a one-liner I can use?

I've been all over http://mailutils.org/manual/mailutils.html, and that's how I know what I need to do - but not how to do it.  Can anyone help?  Thank you.

edit: On Ubuntu 13.10

Comment: `echo 'askcc=false' >> /etc/mailutils.rc` ? You probably need to be an elevated user to create the file with the correct ownership and permissions (root, or something like mailadmin?) You'd also need to be able to restart the mail daemon (another permissions/userAccess issue). Manuals are notorious for not getting into 'how-to-do-it', unless it is has sections or separate docs for 'FAQ (many of these are useless too), or 'How-to'. Look around more on `mailutils.org` and see if there isn't an area for support, users, KB, etc.  Good luck.

Comment: It doesn't appear to like that syntax... I do have root access.

Comment: Tried all permutations of syntax I can think of, can't figure it out.  Hope a mailutils guru stumbles across this...

Comment: `man mailutils` or similar should have a section labeled **files:**. Dbl-check that you've got the exact filename specified for the config. ALSO if there is a section labeled **Environment** (or similar), dbl-check your environment for incorrectly specified values for those variable names. (MBOX on my system is the one that could be causing you problems). Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed mailutils just yesterday and today spent hours trying to set the mail variable "savekeep" to True. The mailutils documentation is poor but I got things to work after finding 
[2.4.7 Personal and System-wide Configuration Files](http://mailutils.org/manual/mailutils.html#SEC107). So then the task is to find out how to write the settings in a mailrc file. You can refer to [.mailrc File Format](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.files%2Fdoc%2Faixfiles%2Fmailrc.htm) on the ibm.com website.
You need to create the file ~you/.mailrc for user configuration or /etc/mail.rc for system wide configuration. Here is what you need to write in the file to set "savekeep" and "askcc".

```
set askcc=False;
set keepsave=True;
```